# SQLAlchemy InvalidRequest on adding to relationship collection

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, flask

I adding kind of 'migration' functionality to my Flask project. Initially I want to add user and roles which relates as many-to-many following way:

```
users_to_roles_association_table = db.Table('users_to_roles',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id')))

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    ..................
    roles = relationship('Role', secondary=users_to_roles_association_table, lazy='dynamic')

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('role_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    rolename = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=False)
    ..................
```

Here is my migration `up` method:

```
def up(self):
  try:
    user = User.query.filter_by(nickname='alp').first()

    if not user:
      user = User(email='some@email.com', nickname='admin', status=USER.Active)
      password = raw_input("Input password for user %s: " % user.nickname)
      user.set_password(password)
      db.session.add(user)

    role = Role.query.filter_by(rolename='Admin').first()
    if not role:
      role = Role(rolename='Admin')
      db.session.add(role)  //HERE

    if not user.is_in_role('Admin'):
      user.roles.append(role)


  except Exception, e:
    print "Rolling back changes"
    db.session.rollback()
    raise
```

whe I run it I've got an exception: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Role at 0x331db50>' is already attached to session '3' (this is '2')`
If I commenting out line `db.session.add(role)` error is gone bu `Role` does not added to database.

I need this logic because some other records may be in table, so I cannot guarentee that specific role isn't exists in database.

How to deal with this error?

Comment: Try doing your select queries before you add anything to the session (ie move the `role = Role.query...` line underneath `user = User.query`) - does that help?

Comment: @DazWorrall, than you for advice, but I tried. Anyway - I found solution, it is related to `db` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I seems that I stepped on the rake due insufficient knowledge of internal Flask architecture.

At the top of my migration file (I using `Flask-Evolution`) there is lines:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(current_app)
db.metadata.bind = main.db.engine
```

I used this variable `db` to operate my records, but due unknown reasons it has its own sesion different from my (I have my own database handler defined in `main.py`: `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`
). When I replaced lines like `db.session....` with `main.db.session...` all becomes working fine. I'll be glad if somebody can explains this situation.

Comment: You've probably figured this out by now, but `SQLAlchemy` comes from Flask-SQLAlchemy, which is different from SQLAlchemy proper. While that second line might get your binds lined up correctly, you'll probably still get a second session when you instantiate (Flask-)`SQLAlchemy` twice.

In our app we instantiate `SQLAlchemy` once during configuration and use the same db variable in the rest of the app. I would put `from main import db` everywhere you need that `SQLAlchemy` object, rather than `db = SQLAlchemy(current_app)`.